# How to remove blocks in XML based on a condition

Tags: python, xml-parsing

My XML file contains 10k users, I need to remove all users where email does not contains @acme.com

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<users type="array">
  <user>
    <id type="integer">14000760626</id>
    <name> Credentialing Department</name>
    <email>user1@acme.com</email>
    <created-at type="dateTime">2020-03-26T10:23:34-04:00</created-at>
    <updated-at type="dateTime">2020-03-26T10:23:34-04:00</updated-at>
    <active type="boolean">false</active>
    <job-title></job-title>
    <phone>1234567890</phone>
    <mobile>1234567890</mobile>
    <description></description>
    <time-zone>Eastern Time (US &amp; Canada)</time-zone>
    <deleted type="boolean">false</deleted>
    <language>en</language>
    <address></address>
    <external-id nil="true"/>
    <helpdesk-agent type="boolean">false</helpdesk-agent>
    <location-name nil="true"/>
    <time-format>12h</time-format>
    <company-names type="array"/>
    <custom_field>
    </custom_field>
  </user>
</users>
```

I tried to follow [how do I filter values from XML file in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2286633/how-do-i-filter-values-from-xml-file-in-python) but got stuck changing the below line:

```
>>> xmldata.xpath('/localization/b[@n="Levels"]/l[@k=$level]/v/text()',level='Level1')
['Beginner Level']
```

I also tried other methods but will always lose some data,example result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<users type="array">
<user>
<id>14000760626</id>
<name> Credentialing Department</name>
<email>test@aoncology.com</email>
<created-at>2020-03-26T10:23:34-04:00</created-at>
<updated-at>2020-03-26T10:23:34-04:00</updated-at>
<active>false</active>
<job-title>None</job-title>
<phone>1234567890</phone>
<mobile>1234567890</mobile>
<description>None</description>
<time-zone>Eastern Time (US & Canada)</time-zone>
<deleted>false</deleted>
<language>en</language>
<address>None</address>
<external-id>None</external-id>
<helpdesk-agent>false</helpdesk-agent>
<location-name>None</location-name>
<time-format>12h</time-format>
<company-names>None</company-names>
<custom_field>
    </custom_field>
</user>

</users>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you are looking for something like this:

Assuming a simplified XML:

```
users = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<users type="array">
  <user>
    <id type="integer">14000760626</id>
    <name> Credentialing Department</name>
    <email>user1@acme.com</email>      
  </user>
  <user>
    <id>14000760626</id>
    <name> Credentialing Department</name>
    <email>test@aoncology.com</email>
   </user>
</users>"""
```

Then:

```
doc = etree.XML(users.encode())
for user in doc.xpath('//users/user'):        
    if not "acme" in user.xpath('./email')[0].text:
        user.getparent().remove(user)
print(etree.tostring(doc).decode())
```

Output:

```
<users type="array">
  <user>
    <id type="integer">14000760626</id>
    <name> Credentialing Department</name>
    <email>user1@acme.com</email>      
  </user>
  </users>
```

from lxml import etree

Comment: Hey Jack - Checking since I am not a dev
So in the terminal:
1) Run users = """<...
2) Run doc = etree.XML(users.encode())
for user in doc.xpath('//users/user'):        
    if not "acme" in user.xpath('./email')[0].text:
        user.getparent().remove(user)
print(etree.tostring(doc).decode())
3) Run from lxml import etree